# why page redirect to home page when try to change language?

Tags: php

Firstly, my problem is whenever i try to change a language in website, the language is change but then it's redirect to home page, not current page. Eventhough the language change is success but how can i make it change on current page?

this code is from inc.language.php file

the code is like this.

//after connect with db

```
if ($numrows_langs>1){

    $languagelist="<form action=\"\" method=\"post\" name=\"language_form\">
                   <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style=\"padding:5px 0px\">
                   <tr>
                        <td style=\"padding-right:5px\">$LANGUAGE</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name=\"lang\" onchange=\"document.language_form.submit();\" style=\"width:110px\">";  
                        while($r_langs=mysql_fetch_array($sql_langs))
                        {
                            $LangID_langs=$r_langs["LangID"];
                            $strName_langs=$r_langs["strName"];
                            $isDefault_langs=$r_langs["isDefault"];

                            if($_SESSION['langid']==$LangID_langs){
                                $showselected=" selected=\"selected\" ";
                            }
                            else{
                                $showselected="$LangID_langs";
                            }

                             $languagelist.="<option value=\"$LangID_langs\" $showselected >$strName_langs</option>";
                        }

           $languagelist.="</select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </form>";
```

}

hope someone can advice me the way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form's `action` element is an empty string, which is interpreted as a relative path without a filename, so it refers to the directory that contains the current page.  In other words, if the page `foo/bar.php` has a `<form action="">`, the form will submit to `foo/`.

You need to put the correct URL in your form's action attribute.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time sir @Wyzard , yes i have noticed the action element before, and also have tried before, but still i cant make it change on current page.